# InputBox: Only allow certain range of values

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

I want to limit the range of accepted values that users can input.

For instance, I want to allow 0-100 only, and if they enter over 100, then

1. automatically enter a default value (such as 10) and
2. create a pop-up message indicating that the default value was applied.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim CO2PriceBox As Variant
    CO2PriceBox = InputBox("Please Enter CO2 Allowance Price ($/ton)", "Enter CO2 Allowance Price", 0)
    Range("C11").Value = CO2PriceBox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Dim CO2PriceBox As Variant

CO2PriceBox = InputBox("Please Enter CO2 Allowance Price ($/ton)", "Enter CO2 Allowance Price", 0)

If Not IsNumeric(CO2PriceBox) Or CO2PriceBox < 0 Or 100 < CO2PriceBox Then 'If value out of specified range

    CO2PriceBox = 10 'Default value
    MsgBox "You Entered a wrong value, using default", vbOKOnly
End If
```

Comment: FYI: The `IsNumeric(CO2PriceBox)` is obsolete as all non-numerical values will trigger an VBA-error at the `<` sign (because it can not be compared). Still, using `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=1` is possible to avoid this by default. ;)

Comment: Thanks! This solution is almost perfect, but one slight issue: I typed it in exactly as stated and it works smoothly, but it doesn't actually revert the value in the cell to the default value (10) if a value entered is outside the range. It corrects it in the dialogue box, but not the actual cell. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, problem solved! I just needed to add "Range("C11").Value = CO2PriceBox" after the line instructing the macro to use the default value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could use Excel [InputBox()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468(v=office.15).aspx) method to build a little "wrapper" function:

```
Function GetValue(prompt As String, title As String, minVal As Long, maxVal As Long, defVal As Long) As Variant
    GetValue = Application.InputBox(prompt & "[" & minVal & "-" & maxVal & "]", title, Default:=defVal, Type:=1)
    If GetValue < minVal Or GetValue > maxVal Then
        GetValue = defVal
        MsgBox "your input exceeded the range: [" & minVal & "-" & maxVal & "]" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "the default value (" & defVal & ") was applied", vbInformation
    End If
End Function
```

and use it as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Range("C11").Value = GetValue("Please Enter CO2 Allowance Price ($/ton)", "Enter CO2 Allowance Price", 0, 100, 10)

End Sub
```